# Using google analytics to track open requests in email

Tags: tracking

Google Analytics, is normaly used to track links on webpages or links within emails.
But I wanted to use it to track when a email message was opened. This would of cause mean that images would need to be shown in the email client.

I am using this with Amazon SES so please do not comment and say to do this with mailchimp.

One provider was doing some thing like this but there site has been down for  very long time

http://web.archive.org/web/20100828084217/http://email-tracking-with-google-analytics.com/index.php

What I am thinking is putting a 1x1 image in a email that is in fact a php script that in turn will call the google Anlytics tracking gif. I do not want to directly place the google Anlytics tracking gif in my outbound email.

if you look at the above site this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The site has been up and running again for the last year. It's out of beta testing now. You can use it to track opened emails using Google Analytics, or just view the reports the tool generates: http://pixelsite.info/.